# Google Username from Email

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail

Lets suppose, I have a list of Gmail accounts:-

1. bobcharles@gmail.com
2. randomuser@gmail.com

Can we extract the names of the users using these mails? Like for the first mail, the user might have the name Bob Charles. Can we find a way to extract these names in bulk without using google sign in.


Please share how to do this. I am using this for finding the usernames of the university students whose emails are known. This is for a website where university students might interact with students who will make an account later on, but their ids must be known right now.

Comment: Like...get everything to the left of the @? That's an easy regex: `(.*)@`. A harder thing would be turning `bobbystander@gmail.com` into a proper name. Should that be Bobby Stander or Bob Bystander?

Comment: No, I want the google user name. Email and username can be different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151557/get-users-first-and-last-name-via-google-api

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511895/how-can-i-get-the-users-first-and-last-name-by-his-gmail and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316092/how-to-get-first-name-and-last-name-by-email-address-gmail-com

Comment: are these users logged into their gmail accounts?  or are you just trying to find the names associated with random emails.